# SSRS Using Outdated Credentials for Emailed Subscriptions to Reports

Tags: reporting-services, subscription

I'm attempting to setup a subscription for emailing reports inside SSRS however when the subscription runs it generates the error:

`The user or group name '[DOMAIN]\[OLDUSER]' is not recognized.`

Which makes sense because the account it's trying to use (OLDUSER) hasn't existed since I renamed my account. As a diagnostic I made a report which only displays `=User!UserID` and it's displaying my correct, current username. I'm not sure where but somewhere in SSRS it's stored these old credentials and I cant find any resources online for how to update them. I've also checked through Reporting Services Configuration Manager and it's using valid credentials throughout.

Any ideas? And thanks for any input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had this issue before. It's been an issue that Microsoft was supposed to fix for 2008 - only 7 or so years.

It's the Owner that needs to be updated.

Check this out:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/miah/archive/2008/07/10/tip-change-the-owner-of-report-server-subscription.aspx.

[image]

Comment: Yes! That wasn't actually exactly the solution but it did lead me to figuring it out. It turns out SQL Server itself never updated it's cached version of my username (despite the change happening years ago) and even manually renaming it wouldn't work. Deleting the account in SQL server and recreating it, setting a couple duplicate records to NULL in the Users table of ReportServer, and a restart was enough to get everything synced back up again and working. Thanks for your help!